# Destructure using rest parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to destructure a React context based on rest parameters passed to the hook.

Say I am passing an array of enums and want to return only the ones that are passed into the hook.

Here's my interface context type

```
enum ConfigItem {
  SomeItem = 'SomeItem',
  AnotherItem = 'AnotherItem',
}

type Config = Record<ConfigItem, boolean>;

type ConfigState = {
  config: Config;
}
```

and the hook itself

```
const useConfig = (...configArgs: ConfigItem) => {
  const configContext = useContext(ConfigContext);
  
  const { config } = configContext;
  const { ...configArgs } = config;  // Duplicate identifier 'configArgs'.

  return configArgs;
}
```

I would like to use it like so

```
const config = useConfig(ConfigItem.SomeItem, ConfigItem.AnotherItem);
```

and that would return an object with relevant properties. I might want to pass a single arg but potentially many.

The above const would return this (true/false is whatever would be in the context but that is not in scope of the question)

```
{
  SomeItem: true/false,
  AnotherItem: true/false,
}
```

but if I would only pass one of them I expect to see a single property.

Answer (score 2):

By their nature, rest parameters are **arrays**, so you need an array type:

```typescript
const useConfig = (...configArgs: ConfigItem[]) => {
//                                          ^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
// ...
```

If you pass just one argument, the array will have one element, but it will still be an array.

---

In a comment you've said:

> My problem is how to return only the provided args properties but thanks for the correction.

If you mean you're having trouble creating the object you want to return, you can do that in a few ways; I'd probably lean toward `Object.fromEntries` (you'll need to polyfill if targeting pre-ES2019 environments):

```typescript
const useConfig = (...configArgs: ConfigItem[]) => {
    const configContext = useContext(ConfigContext);
    
    const { config } = configContext;
    return Object.fromEntries(
        configArgs.map(itemKey => [itemKey, config[itemKey]])
    ) as Record<ConfigItem, boolean>;
};
```

You may need a type guard to avoid

Comment: My problem is how to return only the provided args properties but thanks for the correction.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk - Ah, I thought you were having trouble with the type of the parameter. I've updated the answer.